# Simple fraction problem from book

Tags: fractions

[image]

How does the step from $$=\biggr(\frac{7}{4}\biggr)^{k-2}\biggr(\frac{11}{4}\biggl)$$ To $$=\biggr(\frac{7}{4}\biggr)^{k-2}\biggr(\frac{7}{4}\biggl)^2$$ work given $(\frac{7}{4})^2 \neq (\frac{11}{4})$

Comment: It is $\biggr(\frac{7}{4}\biggr)^{k-2}\biggr(\frac{11}{4}\biggl)<\biggr(\frac{7}{4}\biggr)^{k-2}\biggr(\frac{7}{4}\biggl)^2$

Comment: Wait so when the writer uses the $=$ instead of $<$ for step 2 and 3 its not just short hand it means an actual conversion?

Comment: The writer uses "$=$" because the expressions are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $\displaystyle {(\frac 74)}^{k-2}(\frac {11}4) <{(\frac 74)}^{k-2}(\frac {7}4)^2$ means the left hand term is *less than* the right hand term. It is *not* equality. It is an *inequality*. The expression $a < b$ means that $a$ is less than $b$. The expression $a > b$ means that $a$ is greater than $b$.

And the inequality holds because $\displaystyle (\frac {11}4) < (\frac {7}4)^2$. Do you see now?

Can you see how to prove that $\displaystyle (\frac {11}4) < (\frac {7}4)^2$, or do you need help with this part too?

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhh okay so when $<$ is used with no visible left part then the left part is assumed to be the line above it?

Comment: @SonnyDasilvapeters Yes. Just the same as when you break a line and start the next line with '='. It's just typography, not mathematics.

Comment: I am so sorry i took so much time figuring that out, i'm new to trying to read more mathematical books, thank you so much

Comment: @SonnyDasilvapeters No problem, we all have to start somewhere. :)

Answer (score 3):

$$\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{k-2}\cdot \frac{11}{4}=\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^k\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^2\cdot \frac{11}{4}=\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^k\frac{44}{49}$$

Comment: how is this $$\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^k\frac{44}{49}$$ the same as $$\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{k-2}\biggl(\frac{7}{4}\biggl)^2 = \biggl(\frac{7}{4}\biggl)^k$$ am i making a mistake in one of these?

Comment: $$\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{k-2}\cdot \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^2=\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{k-2+2}=\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^k$$

Comment: But didnt your original answer come out to $$\biggl(\frac{7}{4}\biggl)^k\biggl(\frac{44}{49}\biggl)$$ is it due to the fact that you are proving its greater than that you can ignore the $44/49$??

Comment: so what exactly is your question?

Comment: yes and $$\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{-2}=\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^2$$

Comment: $$=\biggr(\frac{7}{4}\biggr)^{k-2}\biggr(\frac{11}{4}\biggl)$$ To $$=\biggr(\frac{7}{4}\biggr)^{k-2}\biggr(\frac{7}{4}\biggl)^2$$